# MySQL optimization - large table joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

To start out here is a simplified version of the tables involved.

`tbl_map` has approx 4,000,000 rows, `tbl_1` has approx 120 rows, `tbl_2` contains approx 5,000,000 rows. I know the data shouldn't be consider that large given that Google, Yahoo!, etc use much larger datasets. So I'm just assuming that I'm missing something.

```
    CREATE TABLE `tbl_map` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `tbl_1_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '-1',
      `tbl_2_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '-1',
      `rating` decimal(3,3) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `tbl_1_id` (`tbl_1_id`),
      KEY `tbl_2_id` (`tbl_2_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_1` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_2` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `data` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The Query in interest: also, instead of `ORDER BY RAND()`, `ORDERY BY t.id DESC`. The query is taking as much as 5~10 seconds and causes a considerable wait when users view this page.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT t.data, t.id , tm.rating
FROM tbl_2 AS t
JOIN tbl_map AS tm 
ON t.id = tm.tbl_2_id
WHERE tm.tbl_1_id =94
AND tm.rating IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 200 

1   SIMPLE  tm  ref     tbl_1_id, tbl_2_id  tbl_1_id    9   const   703438  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     8   tm.tbl_2_id     1
```

I would just liked to speed up the query, ensure that I have proper indexes, etc.
I appreciate any advice from DB Gurus out there! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SUGGESTION : Index the table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_map ADD INDEX (tbl_1_id,rating,tbl_2_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :) I'll give it a try and let you know how it works. Glad to hear from an actual DBA!

Comment: The index was definitely a huge help. However I the refactoring of the SQL statement now does not return anything. I will continue to see if it just an error on my part.

Comment: The it would left join entries where rating is NULL. Actually my original query and DRapp's work fine after adding the index you mentioned. :)

Comment: The tm subquery explicitly says `AND rating IS NOT NULL`. The tm subquery would only produce a NULL rating if and only if `t.id = tm.tbl_2_id` fails for a given row.

Comment: From my understanding the first select pulls the lass 200 entries from `tbl_2`, the `LEFT JOIN`s from tm. And because it is a `LEFT JOIN`, when the second Select query does not yield a result (i.e. rating IS NULL), the NULL gets returned as tm.rating.

Comment: After running the query this is what seems to happen.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` is from t not tm

Comment: Sorry, typo, what I meant is tm is LEFT JOINed to t, hence the NULL ratings still returning in the query results.

Comment: I change the tm from a subquery back to the table tbl_map and put the WHERE clause back outside the subquery level. Does that produce a better result?

Comment: Sorry that query doesn't return anything >_< But don't worry haha The INDEX you suggested was very helpful for me! :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, If you remove the query from the answer, I will make this the selected answer since you were the first one to suggest indexing, which was what ultimately sped my query up!

Comment: OK, I removed the query from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As per Rolando, yes, you definitely need an index on the map table but I would expand to ALSO include the tbl_2_id which is for your ORDER BY clause of Table 2's ID (which is in the same table as the map, so just use that index.  Also, since the index now holds all 3 fields, and is based on the ID of the key search and criteria of null (or not) of rating, the 3rd element has them already in order for your ORDER BY clause.

INDEX (tbl_1_id,rating, tbl_2_id);

Then, I would just have the query as

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN 
      t.data, 
      t.id , 
      tm.rating
   FROM 
      tbl_map tm
         join tbl_2 t
            on tm.tbl_2_id = t.id
   WHERE 
          tm.tbl_1_id = 94
      AND tm.rating IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY 
      tm.tbl_2_id DESC
   LIMIT 200
```

Comment: After adding the INDEX that Rolando mentioned this query went from taking 60 seconds to 1.2 seconds. so that was nice. I preprended EXPLAIN and it also showed better results. Thanks

Comment: @KennyCason, ok on the index, but how then did my version obviously get the credit... how was ITs explain and overall performance vs the 1.2.  So which was better results...

Comment: I primarily excepted yours because the query worked, but yes, given that ultimately Rolando first mentioned the INDEXing, I can give him credit. As to query performance, after INDEXing the rows, our queries run approximately the same. Thanks.